# In R how can I make the for loop run faster?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, time-series, vectorization

I have the below code, of 2 time series. maxNo is the number of elements in the time series. longStopPrev is the 1 position lagged version of longStop. The variables are initiated before the loop so that their size is not increasing in every iteration. When the maxNo is large, this loop takes a very long time to run.

Is there any clever way to avoid using for loop and vectorize or to make this run faster?

I think the main challenge is that there is a chance for the variable `longStopPrev` to be changed in each run of the loop, which makes it hard to run the operations only one time as a vector. However there could be a better way to execute, similar to different search algorithms.

I have tested using `foreach` but it only made the code run slower. I have also tested changing inside the for loop

```
longStopPrev = stats::lag(longStop, k=1,na.pad = TRUE) # lag 1
```

with:

```
longStopPrev[i+1] <- longStop[i]
```

But the result was slightly slower.

I tried to make a reproducible example below . I test the code with ~10.000 points in my time series and actually want to run with ~100.000 or longer.

```
require("xts")

set.seed(47); n = 1e1;
data <- xts(rnorm(n)+10, 
             order.by = seq(as.POSIXct("2017-05-31 17:00:00"), length=n, by="min"))

diff=0.5
longStop = data - diff

longStopPrev = stats::lag(longStop, k=1,na.pad = TRUE) # lag 1
longStopPrev = na.approx(longStopPrev, rule=2,na.rm = FALSE,maxgap=1) # fill NA values by approx

maxNo <- nrow(longStop)

for(i in 1:maxNo) {
  if(as.numeric(data[i])>as.numeric(longStopPrev[i]) ){
    longStop[i] <- max(longStop[i],longStopPrev[i])
    longStopPrev = stats::lag(longStop, k=1,na.pad = TRUE) # lag 1 
    
  }
}
longStopPrev = na.approx(longStopPrev, rule=2,na.rm = FALSE,maxgap=1) # fill NA values by approx
```

Comment: For a start, do `longStop <- numeric(maxNo)` before you get into your loop - that way you're not dynamically incrementing vector size, which is expensive.

Comment: If you made a reproducible example it would be easier to answer the question.

Comment: @CaptainHat it is already initialized before the loop. I have attached the actual code so that you can see and reproduce.

Comment: Rather than asking us to download an import some data file, please make your example self-contained in the question. Either provide code to simulate a bit of sample data, use a built-in data set, or share a few rows of your data copy/pasteably with `dput(your_data[1:10, ])`.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you for your input. Just a question on that. I measure the time with a time series of ~10.000 rows(~runs for about 15-20 seconds). Would it possible to demonstrate and check if it runs faster on much fewer, say 10 rows?

Comment: In some cases, yes. Without seeing sample data I'm having trouble really knowing what your code does. I think it might be possible to use a vectorized `pmax` or `cummax` or something instead of the loop - a 10-row example is perfect for understanding what's going on and attempting to simplify.

Comment: For incremental improvements (or to get the overall effect), yes, it's good to test on large data, but that's a great use case for sharing a few lines of code to simulate sample data. Something , `set.seed(47); n = 1e5; longStop = rnorm(n)` is a lot nicer to share than a Google drive link. It's a lower bar for entry for answerers, it's stable making the question a better long-term resource as the data won't disappear at any point, and we can adjust `n` even higher if needed to really test the limits.

Comment: @GregorThomas I have initiated the dataset with `rnorm()` as suggested so that it is possible to demonstrate and also scale up. Please let me know if the questions is good like this or any other improvements are suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that converting `xts` to a `matrix` before the for loop using `coredata()` speeds up the code a lot. Apparently calling xts elements is much slower compared to a matrix. at the end of the for loop you can just convert back to `xts` if you need it.